# Network service not working in browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I've written a provider to help track network connectivity using the [Native Network](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) plugin:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Connectivity {
    public online: boolean = false;

    constructor(private network: Network) {
        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            console.log('Network offline');
            this.online = false;
        });

        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
            this.online = true;
            console.log('Network online');
        });
    });
}
}
```

I've installed the relevent plugins (`package.json`):

```
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
...
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
```

And I've included my provider in my `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
    Network,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Connectivity,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
```

Yet, when I run the app in the browser, neither of the observables fire. If I try print: `console.log(this.network.type)` in the provider constructor, it just prints `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is that the native network plugin *doesn't work* in the browser. Even though it has "browser" listed as a supported platform:

[image]

It is referring to the [*Cordova Browser*](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/03/22/the-cordova-browser-platform/) which is different to a web browser. I found this out after discussion on the Ionic Slack channel.

You need to instead write a Provider that:

- Detects platform
- If on a native device, use the native network plugin
- If in a browser, use the browser API

For others with the same problem:

- [Here is some clarification on why you have two different APIs available](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-browser-apis-over-ionic-native-apis/131079)
- [Here is an example of a provider that uses a variety of approaches for finding location](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/code-review-for-flexible-geolocation-provider/131164) (this isn't the same as my question, but is similar in the solution as it uses a browser API as well as the Ionic Native API)

Answer (score 1):

> In my application I use "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^ 2.0.1" 
>    and "@ionic-native / network": "^ 4.6.0"

I can share the same service I use. this is currently working

```
'@ angel / core' import {Injectable};
From the '@ Ionic-native / network' resource {Network};

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Injectable()
export class NetworkProvider {

  constructor(private _network: Network) { }

  isConnectInternet() {
    return this._network.onConnect();
  }

  isDisconnect() {
    return this._network.onDisconnect();
  }

    enter code here

  connectionType() {
    if (this._network.type == 'none' ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this service into my project which is on following environment

```
cli packages: 

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

this is my provider file, network.ts.

```
import { Functions } from './../functions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the NetworkProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/

export enum ConnectionStatusEnum {
  Online,
  Offline
}


@Injectable()
export class NetworkProvider {

  previousStatus;
  constructor(public functions:Functions, 
              public network: Network,
              public eventCtrl: Events) {

                this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
  }

  public initializeNetworkEvents(): void {
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Online) {
            this.eventCtrl.publish('network:offline');
        }
        this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline;
    });
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline) {
            this.eventCtrl.publish('network:online');
        }
        this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
    });
}
```

Comment: im running in emulator and nothing happening. even a single console log. but it finds the detection when i go offline or change from wifi to 4G

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are running

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

not

```
ionic serve
```